# Missing Right Parenthesis Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, parentheses

I am trying to create a table in SQL developer but I get an error saying:

```
Error SQL: ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis.
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE PACIENTE (
    IdentificacionID integer(5),
    TipoIdentificacionID integer(5),
    Nombre varchar(30),
    Apellido varchar(30),
    NumeroHistoriaClinica integer(5)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `INTEGER`. You should be using `NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE PACIENTE (
    IdentificacionID number(5),
    TipoIdentificacionID number(5),
    Nombre varchar(30),
    Apellido varchar(30),
    NumeroHistoriaClinica number(5)
);
```

I agree the error message is confusing though! Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4fa10).

Comment: Thank you so much!! but now in the sql developer is a new error saying that identifier is too long in the varchars, so you know what could it be?

Comment: @Danielesk Do you have a column name longer than 30 chars? If not, can you post a new question with the query you're trying to run and put the link here?